Using custom table definitions in a multi statment table function
I have a custom type and a table, and I want to reuse this as a return result for several table functions. I want to declare the type rather than recreate the definition. So the start of the function would look like:
CREATE Function Function(@Param1 INT, @Param2 INT)
RETURNS TABLE MyTableType
AS
BEGIN
...

This does not seem possible - which strikes me as a deficiency. Are there any suggestions?

No, it's not possible.
The syntax grammar is quite clear:
-- Syntax for Transact-SQL multi-statement table-valued functions.  
CREATE [ OR ALTER ] FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type [ NULL ]
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] }
    [ , ...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS @return_variable TABLE <table_type_definition>
    [ WITH <function_option> [ , ...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    BEGIN
        function_body
        RETURN
    END
[ ; ]

You can see the line RETURNS @return_variable TABLE <table_type_definition> only allows a TABLE definition, not a table type:
<table_type_definition> ::=
( { <column_definition> <column_constraint>
  | <computed_column_definition> }
    [ <table_constraint> ] [ , ...n ]
)

Etc.
Having said that, Multi-Statement Table Valued Functions are usually really bad for performance, and can nearly always be rewritten as Inline TVFs instead. So you won't need a table definition anyway, as the single SELECT statement does that automatically.
